# XP SP3 issue with wireless connection

Tags: windows-xp, wireless-networking, sp3, wpa2-psk

I have a fresh install of XP SP3 on my sister's laptop and the wireless connection is not working correctly. Her router is using WPA2-PSK (AES) encryption on a mixed bgn connection. The laptop connects to the wireless, gets an IP over DHCP (sometimes an IP conflict message apperars) but does not have a proper connection: ping on anything other than its own IP is unresolved.

I've inputted the proper IP, Mask, Gateway and DNS and ping is still not working. A windows 7 installation, my phone had no issue connecting to her wireless. On a Ubuntu 12.10 live everything works like a charm. I even had the laptop on my house and it connected with no issues on my wireless connection.

We even have similar router configurations I use an 802.11g-only mode (compared with mixed bgn)  and probably I use WPA2-PSK (I am not sure if I use WPA or WPA2 since the router is set to automatically select the encryption.)

I am out on ideas so I thought of asking for help.

ps: I think her pass phrase is slightly longer but I think once the authentication is completed the keys are not related to the password. So this should not be an issue.

Comment: Her laptop may not support WPA2 (and that's what your router is actually doing, which is why it works and hers doesn't with the laptop.

Comment: If safe to do so, remove the password completely and see if you can get on (at least this will rule it out). Also, can you ping the router?